# Git exclude: include only specific directory and its subdirectories

Tags: wordpress, git

## Problems

I've looked at all the relevant questions on SO, so if the answer does happen to be in there, I apologize.

Here's the problem: I want to exclude everything but one directory and all of its contents (including sub directories).
The working dir is a WordPress install, and for this specific repo I only want to include `wp-content/themes/*`
The only way I can get it to work, is if I do this:

```
# Blacklist everything
*
# Whitelist all directories
!*/
# Whitelist anything you want to include
!wp-content/themes/*
!wp-content/themes/*/*
!wp-content/themes/*/*/*
!wp-content/themes/*/*/*/*
!wp-content/themes/*/*/*/*/*
!wp-content/themes/*/*/*/*/*/*
!wp-content/themes/*/*/*/*/*/*/*
!wp-content/themes/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*
!wp-content/themes/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*
!wp-content/themes/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*
!wp-content/themes/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*
```

Now this seems silly and feels like I'm doing it wrong. It will also not work for directories with more levels than specified here. The `*` line seems to tell Git to ignore any sub-directory, even if the negating pattern seems to include it.

## Solutions

Both of the following answers work:
**#1**

```
*
!*/
!wp-content/themes/**
```

**#2**

```
*
!wp-content/
!wp-content/themes/
!wp-content/themes/**
```

**#3**

```
/*
!/wp-content
/wp-content/*
!/wp-content/themes
```

Could anyone tell me if one is more efficient than the other, or is it purely preference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `**` to match all subdirectories. This should work:

```
*
!wp-content/
!wp-content/themes/
!wp-content/themes/**
```

Comment: The annoying thing is that I tried this, but in conjunction with the `!/*`, which makes it not work.. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In a very large repo [Klas Mellbourn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30431812/1290731) shows how to avoid enough unnecessary scans that it'll save noticeable time (just like `find` on a big tree) the first time, but they tend to stay cached.  For almost everything your `!*/` followed by any content inclusions works great. So:

```
*
!*/
!wp-content/themes/**
```

It also gets you one-directory-per-line inclusion no matter how deep it is.

Answer (score 1):

My take on it:

Ignore everything in this folder (the root folder) except wp-content, and then ignore everything inside wp-content except themes.

This way you are not ignoring everything and having to readd it back, only the 2 folders you want to track. (The `/*` line goes as is, it is not a comment)

```
/*
!/wp-content
/wp-content/*
!/wp-content/themes
```